# Color class in scatter_matrix with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, colors

I have a matrix x with data, where each row has a class, and a vector y that indicates the type of class (it can be 0 or 1). I want to plot a scatter matrix of x where each type of class has a color (for example green for the 1's and blue for the 0's). I have tried with

```
#Define the color for each class
c={0.0:'blue',1.0:'green'}  
#Plot it
df = pnd.DataFrame(x,columns=['PC1', 'PC2', 'PC3', 'PC4'])
pnd.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(10, 10), color=c[y], diagonal='None')
```

Maybe it doesn't make any sense, but I'm new in Python and I don't now much about it. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your intent is not clear. In a scatter matrix each point represents the intersection between two columns (PC1, PC2, etc). If I add `x=np.random.random([50,4])` to your code and remove the `color=c[y]` part, I get a scatter plot matrix. What would you desire as far as coloring?

Comment: @CPBL it's clear to me; `c[y]` would be a Series containing the color for each point; the same colors would be applied to every panel of the plot